# How to add the Env variable to running docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm running one container with default env variables(like PORTS=1234,1235,1236) already defined from  dockerfile

So with help of this while runtime, executing the script to run the naming services on defined ports

Once the container running , i want to start naming service on 1237,1238  along with existing ports, without stopping the existing container.

Let me know if anybody need more info

Please suggest the best approach

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind containers are single processes that run an application and are self contained. However that case doesn't always work and you need to run multiple things in a single container, to achieve the automatic kick off of the services you should create a SCRIPT file, and use the `ADD` command in the docker file to get it in the system then use the `ENTRYPOINT` section to execute the said script.

If you are really wanting it to be at runtime instead of on startup of container you can do one of the following.

1. Add SSH capabilities to the container (bad idea)
2. Start the container with the `-i` "interactive" switch and the entry point as a shell environment to allow you to attach/detach to the container (not recommended).